# How to create a page and attach a category to your page template automatically?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a custom page template that pulls in post entries based on category. I'm currently using query post with the category name to pull them (page and category are the same). I was wondering if there is a way to make it so I don't have to create a page template for each category/page?

Answer (score 0):

I seems easier to me to just create a category template in category.php, and let the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png) deal with the queries.

However, if there really is a pressing need to do this as a Page, and the page's slug is always the same as a category's slug, a custom query could also achieve what you are asking for:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'category_name' => $post->post_name ) );

    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();

        // This is inside your custom category Loop,
        // where all your category posts' magic will happen
        the_title( '<h2>' , '</h2>' );
        the_content();

    endwhile; endif;

endwhile; endif;

?>
```

Comment: Appreciate the advice regarding the Cat Template. THank you.

Comment: How would I use the code above? I tried it and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: There was no output in the inner loop. I have updated the code to output title and content for every post in the category.